# Div, Ocupar todo el Alto disponible en Table

Tags: reactjs, table, style

Como puedo hacer que un div ocupe todo el Alto de una fila en la `tabla`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy usando `React Styled` pero no logro hacer que este exapnda al `100%`

```
export const CustomTD = styled.td`
  padding: 0px;
  & div {
    color: ${({ fontColor }) => (fontColor ? fontColor : '#004772')};
    display: flex;
    justify-content: ${({ justifyContent }) =>
      justifyContent ? justifyContent : 'center'};
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 2rem;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: ${({ flexDirection }) =>
      flexDirection ? flexDirection : 'initial'};
    background-color: ${({ backgroundColor }) =>
      backgroundColor ? backgroundColor : '#adf620'};
    margin: 3px 0px;
    padding: 3px;
  }
`;
```

```
             <CustomTD
                flexDirection='column'
                backgroundColor='#EDF2F5'
                justifyContent='left'
                fontColor='#004574'
                rowSpan={(rejections || []).length > 0 ? rejections.length : 1}>
                <div>{rejs.title}</div>
              </CustomTD>
```

Answer (score 0):

esto solo es un efecto visual:

```
const CustomTD = styled.td`
  padding: 0px;
    background-color: ${({ backgroundColor }) =>
      backgroundColor ? backgroundColor : '#adf620'};
  & div {
    color: ${({ fontColor }) => (fontColor ? fontColor : '#004772')};
    display: flex;
    justify-content: ${({ justifyContent }) =>
      justifyContent ? justifyContent : 'center'};
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 2rem;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: ${({ flexDirection }) =>
      flexDirection ? flexDirection : 'initial'};
    margin: 3px 0px;
    padding: 3px;
  }
`;
```

lo otro seria que supieras cuantos valores va atener el siguiente td si es así puedes calcular pasándole un parámetro como el :

```
rowSpan={(rejections || []).length > 0 ? rejections.length : 1}
```

algo como eso y en el componente de styled agregarle 30px en height por cada numero, ejemplo al llevar 1 agregar 30px al llevar dos que sean 60px etc.